# Run VS.NET 2008 Web Application With Non-Default Browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have Firefox set as my default browser, but I want to `debug` the ASP.NET Web Application with IE. Searching SO only shows replies to "Browse with ..." However, this doesn't start the debugger. How would I do this? I remember in an old Visual Studio setting the browser to start with the debugger, but I don't remember how - and where it is in VS 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Go to default.aspx` -> `right click it` -> `select browse with` -> `set IE as default browser` -> `run the app`

Comment: Will this change my default browser PC-wide, or just in the context of debugging in Visual Studio?

Comment: Its for visual studio, give it a try and check! :)

Comment: Okay. That starts it. But why doesn't debugging stop when the IE window that spawned is closed? VS 2005 stopped the debugger this way. Is it another setting?

Comment: It should stop it when you close the browser(IE) as far as I know, even in VS 2008 (I always used this!)

Comment: Okay. I'll mess around with it a little more. Thanks!